# auth0 for android token working even after changing the package name & key hashes

Tags: android, auth0

I have integrate auth0 in my app for login process and I have also confirured the App pakcage name & key hashed under auth0 app -> Advanced settings -> Device settings.

After that I have changed the package name and save it but it is still working in my app.

What is the use of device settings and how it can be useful?

I have implement the auth0 and verify the certain settings but it is still not working.

If I change the package name & key hashes then it should not popup the login page.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.